Why are Tarski Monster Groups named after Tarski?
Tarski Monster Groups are named after Tarski in every source I've seen, but I can't find anything about them attributed to Tarski. Did he conjecture their existence or something?

Not sure why this was down-voted, but did you know there’s also history of science and mathematics stack exchange?

Tarski conjectured existence of such groups.

I assume the downvotes come from people who rightfully expect more context. It's a problem statement question, and such questions should not be rewarded. The reasons are explained here. (If the OP indeed searched in the literature, the body of the question should explain this in more detail.) I didn't downvote, by the way.

According to
Kegel, Otto H.; Wehrfritz, Bertram A. F., Locally finite groups, North-Holland Mathematical Library. Vol. 3. Amsterdam-London: North-Holland Publishing Comp.; New York: American Elsevier Publishing Comp., Inc. XI, 210 p. (1973). ZBL0259.20001.
page 30, Alfred Tarski conjectured existence of (necessarily 2-generated) infinite groups where every proper subgroup is of prime order $p$. The book refers to such (at that time, conjectural) groups as Tarski monsters.
